# How do I read coordinates from a csv file into Python?

Tags: python, csv, qgis

I am trying to read the coordinates from a csv file in order to perform clustering with this data. I am struggling to correctly read the coordinates. This is the code I have tried so far:

```
with open('buildingpoints.csv') as file:
     data = [(X, Y) for X, Y in csv.reader(file)]
    for row in data
        print(row)
```

I have attached a screenshot of the csv file from which I am trying to extract the information. Any help would be appreciated

[image: csv file with coordinates]

Comment: Why not use `pandas`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: add more explanation

---

`csv.reader` return a iterator, if you iterate it, it yields one row(list, splited by delimeter) per loop.

your problem is there are too many values(columns) to unpack, `X, Y` is not enough to contain all the values in one row.

`csv.DictReader` do almost same with `csv.reader` but yield a dictionary-based row instead of list-based row. So you can access field with field name.

more detail in [python csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

use `csv.DictReader`

```
import csv

with open('buildingpoints.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['X'], row['Y'])
```

Comment: Just seen your answer after posting mine. But you haven't included much explanation. If you can please add some more explanation then I can delete my answer.

Comment: @alaniwi my answer has been updated, advice welcome :D.

Comment: Okay that looks enough detail - I've removed my answer now. You might want to convert the values to float though.

Comment: @NeoKo thank you. I then used np.array to put the coordinates in an array

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop through twice.

```
with open('buildingpoints.csv') as file:
    for row in csv.reader(file):
        x, y = row
        print(x, y)
```

Comment: But there are more columns than that. You will probably need `x, y = row[:2]`.  (And discard the header row, and convert to float.)

Comment: Yes, I was just showing the critical component to OP. His list comprehension is flawed as each row returns a single tuple containing multiple values.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the issue though. If the file only had two columns and no header row, then his code would actually work (once he tidies up the indentation and adds the missing colon).